# How do I build ArangDB from source on Windows10/11?

Tags: c++, windows, arangodb, building

Hi I'm working on my bachelor's group assignment and I am tasked with building fork of ArangoDB, we have not made any changes to it yet, because I need to be able to build it first. And I have never built a big C++ project, so after of testing and failing for 3 weeks I am now asking for help.

I am trying to build ArangoDB from source, but I can't get past the build errors. It seems like the documentation I can find is outdated and there are no videos out there either that I can find that helps me out. I have looked up how to build C++ projects and followed this guide for that: https://github.com/HO-COOH/CPPDevOnWindows. So the "Hello World" test project works, but when I try to build ArangoDB with its extra dependencies following this guide: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/installation-compiling-windows.html I get a lot of failed tests and errors about not finding openssl when I have it installed (It finds it when it goes through a system wide check) and that I have an outdated camke version installed when I have installed the latest version.

I am using ArangoDB 3.10, Visual Stuido 2019 Community and I have tried installing the dependencies with chocolatey and with MSYS2 and vcpkg.

After installing the dependencies, I tried running "$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" .." in a directory called "Build64" that I created in the ArangoDB source directory. This was after I uninstalled openssl from my computer to try and see if it would use the openssl package I have installed with vcpkg. Normally the cmake command runs for a long time, but when uninstalled openssl it stopped when it could not find openssl in my system.

This is the output:

```
\`C:\\Users\\BJ-X1\\source\\repos\\arangodb\\Build64\>cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..
\-- CMake version: 3.25.3
\-- Building for processor
\-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found suitable version "2.39.1.windows.1", minimum required is "1.5.3")
\-- ARANGODB PLAIN VERSION: 3.10.5
\-- ARANGODB VERSION: 3.10.5
\-- ARANGODB JS VERSION: js
\-- DEBIAN VERSION: 3.10.5 / 1
\-- RPM VERSION:    3.10.5 / 1.0
\-- DARWIN VERSION: 3.10.5 /
\-- WINDOWS VERSION: 3.10.5
\-- SNAP REVISION: 1
\-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
\-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
\-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
\-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
\-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
\-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
\-- Detecting CXX compile features
\-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
\-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
\-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
\-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
\-- Detecting C compile features
\-- Detecting C compile features - done
\-- Found PythonInterp: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python3.exe (found suitable exact version "3.9.10")
\-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
\-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
\-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
\-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
\-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
\-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
\-- Found Threads: TRUE
\-- IPO_ENABLED: False
\-- Compiler type MSVC: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
Required OpenSSL version: 1.1.1\*
Use OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin
Attempt to find ArangoDB CI compiled OpenSSL:
\-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
System-wide attempt to find OpenSSL:
CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found
version "3.0.8")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (\_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:613 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:1202 (find_package)

\-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/BJ-X1/source/repos/arangodb/Build64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/BJ-X1/source/repos/arangodb/Build64/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".\`
```

Just solving these erros will not be enough I think, because when I had installed openssl I got even more after this. Therefore I am wondering if there are an updated guide or documentation on how I should build ArangoDb on windows. Or something that will help with this. Is it better to just switch to Linux(This is ok for me, but worse for my team members).

Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

I manage to build a .sln file and visual stuio looks like this now:
[Screenshot of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LduLw.png)

I used this command:

cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T "v142,host=x64" -DUSE_MAINTAINER_MODE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DSTATIC_EXECUTABLES=ON -DUSE_STRICT_OPENSSL_VERSION=OFF "-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:/msys64/usr/" "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/Python311/python.exe" ..

This was the cmake command output:

```
-- CMake version: 3.25.3
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found suitable version "2.39.1.windows.1", minimum required is "1.5.3")
-- ARANGODB PLAIN VERSION: 3.11.0
-- ARANGODB VERSION: 3.11.0-devel
-- ARANGODB JS VERSION: js
-- WINDOWS VERSION: 3.11.0-devel
-- SNAP REVISION: 1
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30148.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python311/python.exe (found suitable exact version "3.11")
CMake Warning at cmake/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake:22 (message):
  MSVC compiler version C(19.29.30148.0)/C++(19.29.30148.0) is too old.  Need
  at least 19.32.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:496 (CheckCompilerVersion)


-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Building for processor AMD64
-- Could NOT find FLEX (missing: FLEX_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find BISON (missing: BISON_EXECUTABLE)
-- IPO_ENABLED: False
-- Compiler type MSVC: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
Required OpenSSL version: 1.1.1*
Use OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: C:/msys64/usr/
Attempt to find ArangoDB CI compiled OpenSSL:
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
System-wide attempt to find OpenSSL:
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcrypto.a (found version "3.0.8")
C:/msys64/mingw64/include
-- Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/zlib/zlib-1.2.13/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-suggest-override
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-suggest-override - Failed
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-sign-compare
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-sign-compare - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-suggest-override
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-suggest-override - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-sign-compare
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-sign-compare - Failed
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for windows.h
-- Looking for windows.h - found
-- Looking for zlibVersion in z
-- Looking for zlibVersion in z - not found
-- Looking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in lzo2
-- Looking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in lzo2 - not found
-- Looking for LZ4_compress_default in lz4
-- Looking for LZ4_compress_default in lz4 - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_VISUAL_STUDIO_ARCH_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_VISUAL_STUDIO_ARCH_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_VISUAL_STUDIO_ARCH_AVX2
-- Performing Test HAVE_VISUAL_STUDIO_ARCH_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLANG_MAVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLANG_MAVX - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLANG_MBMI2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CLANG_MBMI2 - Failed
-- Performing Test SNAPPY_HAVE_NO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS
-- Performing Test SNAPPY_HAVE_NO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_EXPECT
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_EXPECT - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZ
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZ - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_ALWAYS_INLINE
-- Performing Test HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_ALWAYS_INLINE - Failed
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - not found
-- Looking for sysconf
-- Looking for sysconf - not found
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/V8/CMakeLists.txt:7 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Building V8 for Windows with MSBUILD
-- setting GYP_MSVS_VERSION to 2019
V8_LIBRARY_DEBUG C:/Users/BJ-X1/source/repos/opgDBv02/Build64/3rdParty/V8/gypfiles/Debug CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR C:/Users/BJ-X1/source/repos/opgDBv02/Build64/3rdParty/V8
-- Performing Test ABSL_INTERNAL_AT_LEAST_CXX17
-- Performing Test ABSL_INTERNAL_AT_LEAST_CXX17 - Success
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-const-variable
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-const-variable - Failed
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-mismatched-tags
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-mismatched-tags - Failed
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-function
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-function - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-const-variable
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-const-variable - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-mismatched-tags
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-mismatched-tags - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-function
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-unused-function - Failed
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * Git (required version >= 1.5.3)
 * PythonInterp (required version == 3)
 * OpenSSL
 * Threads

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * GFLAGS, allows changing command line flags.
 * GLOG, provides logging configurability.
 * SHARED_LIBS, builds shared libraries instead of static.
 * PYTHON, provides python interface to S2

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * FLEX
 * BISON
 * Python

GTEST_ROOT:
-- using 3rdParty BOOST
-- Require C++20
-- VelocyPack build mode: RelWithDebInfo
-- VelocyPack interprocedural optimizations: False
-- VelocyPack install base directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/arangodb3
-- Hardware support for SSE4.2 on this machine:
-- Compiler type MSVC: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Building with SSE 4.2 optimizations enabled: ON
-- VelocyPack Building with hash type: xxhash
-- VelocyPack building bench performance test suite: OFF
-- VelocyPack building support programs and tools: OFF
-- VelocyPack building examples: OFF
-- VelocyPack building test suite: OFF
-- VelocyPack building large tests: OFF
-- VelocyPack building assembler test suite: OFF
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/iresearch/CMakeLists.txt:7 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0074 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- IPO_ENABLED: False
-- gprof generation NOT AVAILABLE - Not a GNU compiler
-- target changed from "" to "auto"
-- Detected CPU: kaby-lake
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_AVX2
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_AVX2 - Failed
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_AVX
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_AVX - Failed
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_SSE2
-- Performing Test check_cxx_compiler_flag__arch_SSE2 - Failed
-- Could NOT find BFD (missing:  BFD_INCLUDE_DIR BFD_SHARED_LIBS BFD_STATIC_LIBS BFD_INCLUDE_DIR_ANSIDECL BFD_INCLUDE_DIR_BFD BFD_SHARED_LIB BFD_STATIC_LIB BFD_STATIC_LIB_IBERTY BFD_STATIC_LIB_Z)
BFD_INCLUDE_DIR:
BFD_LIBRARY_DIR:
BFD_SHARED_LIBS:
BFD_STATIC_LIBS:
BFD_SHARED_LIB_RESOURCES:
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/lz4/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt:37 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wall
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wall - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wextra
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wextra - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wundef
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wundef - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_qual
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_qual - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_align
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_align - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wshadow
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wshadow - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wswitch_enum
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wswitch_enum - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wdeclaration_after_statement
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wdeclaration_after_statement - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wstrict_prototypes
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wstrict_prototypes - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wpointer_arith
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wpointer_arith - Failed
-- Performing Test CFLAG_W4
-- Performing Test CFLAG_W4 - Failed
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/iresearch/external/snowball/CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (Perl) does
  not match the name of the calling package (Snowball).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPerl.cmake:84 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  3rdParty/iresearch/external/snowball/CMakeLists.txt:17 (INCLUDE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Perl: echo (found version "-V:version")
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WALL
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WALL - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_W
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_W - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPOINTER
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPOINTER - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPARAM
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPARAM - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WFUNCTION
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WFUNCTION - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WUNUSED_VAR
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WUNUSED_VAR - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPOINTER_SIGN
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WPOINTER_SIGN - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_PEDANTIC_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_PEDANTIC_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_STD_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_STD_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_FPIC
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_FPIC - Failed
-- Could NOT find Unwind (missing:  Unwind_INCLUDE_DIR Unwind_SHARED_LIBS Unwind_STATIC_LIBS UNWIND_SHARED_LIBRARY_CORE UNWIND_STATIC_LIBRARY_CORE UNWIND_SHARED_LIBRARY_PLATFORM UNWIND_STATIC_LIBRARY_PLATFORM)
Unwind_INCLUDE_DIR: Unwind_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
Unwind_LIBRARY_DIR:
Unwind_SHARED_LIBS:
Unwind_STATIC_LIBS:
Unwind_SHARED_LIB_RESOURCES:
LZMA shared library not found. Required if during linking the following errors are seen: undefined reference to `lzma_...
LZMA static library not found. Required if during linking the following errors are seen: undefined reference to `lzma_...
-- Performing Test HWY_EMSCRIPTEN
-- Performing Test HWY_EMSCRIPTEN - Failed
-- Using -std=c++17
CMake Deprecation Warning at 3rdParty/iresearch/external/fastText/CMakeLists.txt:9 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


Submodule path 'rocksdb': checked out 'a3d085c9e20126d462f998bb67172d943779a2b4'
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- GFLAGS library is disabled
-- SNAPPY library is enabled
-- LZ4 library is enabled
-- ZLIB library is disabled
-- XPRESS is disabled
-- ZSTD library is disabled
-- JEMALLOC library is disabled
-- Enabling RTTI in all builds
-- Performing Test HAVE_FALLOCATE
-- Performing Test HAVE_FALLOCATE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP - Failed
-- Looking for malloc_usable_size
-- Looking for malloc_usable_size - not found
-- Looking for sched_getcpu
-- Looking for sched_getcpu - not found
-- Looking for getauxval
-- Looking for getauxval - not found
-- Looking for F_FULLFSYNC
-- Looking for F_FULLFSYNC - not found
-- ROCKSDB_PLUGINS:
-- ROCKSDB PLUGINS TO BUILD
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.39.1.windows.1")
fatal: no tag exactly matches 'a3d085c9e20126d462f998bb67172d943779a2b4'
-- JNI library is disabled
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-implicit-function-declaration
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-implicit-function-declaration - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-implicit-function-declaration
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-implicit-function-declaration - Failed
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - failed
Submodule path 'immer': checked out 'a814bcd5929dc6730f5d713a870fcb1e23af0bf2'
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "1.8.0")
-- Found GC library: BOEHM_GC_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find Boehm_GC (missing:  BOEHM_GC_LIBRARIES BOEHM_GC_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could not find ccache
Submodule path 'fmt': checked out 'a33701196adfad74917046096bf5a2aa0ab0bb50'
-- Module support is disabled.
-- Version: 9.1.0
-- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
-- CXX_STANDARD: 20
-- Required features: cxx_variadic_templates
-- extINFO -- arango-validation tests disabled
-- RELATIVE_ARANGO_ICON: resources\\arangodb.ico
-- ARANGO_IMG:  C:\\Users\\BJ-X1\\source\\repos\\opgDBv02\\Installation\\Windows\\Icons\\arangodb.bmp
-- ARANGO_ICON: C:\\Users\\BJ-X1\\source\\repos\\opgDBv02\\Installation\\Windows\\Icons\\arangodb.ico
-- W_SBIN_DIR: bin bin
-- W_BIN_DIR: bin bin
-- building for git revision: heads/devel-0-g85e3350244-dirty
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/BJ-X1/source/repos/opgDBv02/Build64
```

As you see there are still lots of "Not found warnings" and "Failed warnings".

Comment: I tried opening the arangodb repo in visual studio and there it found the openssl package, but I also got this warning:

CMake Deprecation Waring 3rdParty/zlib/zlib-1.2.12/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.
 
Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

And this error: failed with: ninja: error: build.ninja:9083: multiple rules generate bin/lz4.lib [-w dupbuild=err]

Comment: Install OpenSSL in msys2 using pacman.

Comment: ***Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of CMake. Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.*** This is a warning for the developers of the CMakeLists.txt for ArangoDb. It's not important for you.  In a CMakeLists.txt you as a developer specify the minimum CMake version that your CMakeLists.txt supports. The warning is that eventually CMake will not support backward compatibility for such an old version of CMake.

Comment: More info about that here: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/command/cmake_minimum_required.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/command/cmake_minimum_required.html)

Comment: Typo: "camke" instead of "CMake"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command line I use for building on Windows:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T "v142,host=x64" -DUSE_MAINTAINER_MODE=ON -DUSE_GOOGLE_TESTS=ON -DUSE_ENTERPRISE=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DSKIP_PACKAGING=ON -DUSE_FAILURE_TESTS=ON -DSTATIC_EXECUTABLES=ON -DUSE_STRICT_OPENSSL_VERSION=OFF "-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64" ..
```

The most important option for you is `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` because it tells cmake where to find your OpenSSL installation, so you need to put in your path here. You probably also want to set `USE_STRICT_OPENSSL_VERSION` to `OFF` as in this example. Regarding the other options most of them are optional. The most relevant option for you if you want to work on the code is `USE_MAINTAINER_MODE` which enables additional checks and assertions using the `TRI_ASSERT` macro.

Comment: I tried with this command: 

'cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T "v142,host=x64" -DUSE_MAINTAINER_MODE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DSTATIC_EXECUTABLES=ON -DUSE_STRICT_OPENSSL_VERSION=OFF "-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:/msys64/usr/" "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/Python311/python.exe" ..'

This build the arangodb3.sln file and I can run that without erros, but the cmake command still produces a lot of messages that concern me like: "Attempt to find ArangoDB CI Compiled OpenSSL: Could not find", "Could NOT find Python", "Building for processor AMD64"(I have intel), "COULD NOT find Unwind